# Saving Class-objects in javascript (Circular references ) -> JSON.stringify-error

Tags: javascript, class, cookies, stringify

I am wondering if there are any other ways of saving a Class in javascript.
I have allready tried to serialize with JSON.stringify(), but this returns and error since some of the classes refer to each other(Person and Table).

I know it is possible to write custom save methods to each class type, and to write custom initializer for each class using ID's instead of pointers. But I am wondering for future scenerios, if maybe I can customize the JSON.stringify, or if a class have custom print function, or you can write one like you can in python.

Custom print and save methods for classes?

Possible to save and instance of a Class in a cookie?

Classes:
Project

```
class Project{
constructor(room, name, id, guests, allowedModerators,creationDate, creationUser, plannedDate){
    this.room = room || undefined;
    this.name = name || "Ditt Prosjekt";
    this.id = id || generateID();
    this.guests = guests || [];
    this.allowedModerators = allowedModerators || [];
    this.creationDate = new Date(creationDate) || new Date().getTime();
    this.creationUser = creationUser || undefined; // Pointer ID
    this.plannedDate = new Date(plannedDate) || undefined;
    this.setCreationDate();
}
//Methods...
}
```

Person

```
class Person{
constructor(firstName, surName, age, gender, email, allergies, id, table, seat){
    if(arguments.length == 1 && typeOf(arguments[0]) == "object"){
        //check if they are object for import
    }else{
        this.firstName = firstName || undefined;
        this.surName = surName || undefined;;
        this.age = age || undefined;;
        this.gender = gender || undefined;;
        this.email = email ||undefined;
        this.allergies = allergies || [];
        this.id = id || generateID();
        this.table = table || undefined; //pointer
        this.seat = seat || undefined;
    }
}
//Methods...
}
```

Table

```
class Bord{
constructor(positionX, positionY, bordType, rotation, descriptor){
    this.id = idCounter;
    idCounter++;
    this.persons = [];
    this.seats = [];
   
    
    this.seats = new SeatController(this);
}
}
```

SeatController

```
class SeatController{
constructor(parentTable){
    this.table = parentTable;
    let tempValue = parentTable.returnCenter();
    this.numberOfSeats = parentTable.returnNumberOfSeats();
    this.seats = [];
    
 }   
}
```

[Simple Class Structure][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4FHw.png**strong text**

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` accepts a second `replacer` function that modifies its behavior. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify. Does that do what you need?

Comment: Yes, give your classes  `.toJSON()` methods that do return objects without circular references.